# Exporting Site Configuration Settings into Features

Tags: 6, features

This is on a Drupal 6 site, and we want to export several settings (like CSS aggregation) into features, however it doesn't appear like there's anyway to do this. Do we need to write a custom feature hook?

We installed Ctools and are going to install Features Extra, but nothing seems to support CSS aggregation - a basic site configuration setting - out of the box.

How can we accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to export Drupal 6 system settings like the CSS and JS aggregation. Or anything else stored in the {variables} table, you can use the strongarm module. https://www.drupal.org/project/strongarm

Comment: Yes, I was going to answer this myself when I got to it, but you got to it first. Thanks!